# Error propagation of complex quantity in polar coordinates?

Tags: complex-numbers, error-propagation

Suppose I have a complex number
$C = \left | C \right | e^{i\phi}$ where | | denotes modulus and $\phi$ is the phase angle.

Now, I know the error in the modulus, $\delta |C|$ and error in the phase, $\delta\phi$. What are the error propagation rules to determine the overall error, $\delta C$?

Edit: The "error" I'm referring to is 1 standard deviation.

Comment: How are you defining error?

Comment: 1 standard deviation.

Answer (score 1):

Error propagation is estimated by differentials, so letting $C = re^{i\phi}$, we have $dC = \frac{\partial C}{\partial r}dr + \frac{\partial C}{\partial \phi}d\phi = \frac {C}{r}dr + iCd\phi$. Or in your notation:
$$ \frac{\delta C}{C} = \frac {\delta |C|}{|C|} + i\delta \phi$$

Comment: Using this, lets say I know $\delta C$, $C$, and $\delta |C|$ and I am solving for $\delta \phi$. Wouldn't this result in:

$\delta \phi = \frac{1}{i}\left ( \frac{\delta C}{C}-\frac{\delta |C|}{|C|}\right )$?



This results in imaginary errors in the phase, which seems non-physical

Comment: @Darcy - No it doesn't. $\delta C$ and $C$ are complex numbers. The real part of their ratio is $\frac{\delta |C|}{|C|}$. Since these are approximate values, there maybe a small error that can include an imaginary part, but that is only measurement error.